# Deleting data from MySQL table periodically

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, tidb, table-partitioning

We are using MySQL where we have almost around 100 tables. Data in these tables grow with time. So we need to delete the older data periodically. I think there are two approaches for this. First is to use delete query in batches and second is to use partitioning. So I had following questions

1. Do we really need to use partitioning if we can delete the data in batches of say 5000 records?
2. I read that data deletion causes fragmentation, wont partition deletion cause same issue?
3. If we use partitioning, Instead of creating partitions frequently, can we create partitions for an year in advance? So that we will have to create partitions only once? (FYI, 20% of the table would have partition of 1 day, 50% would have partition of 7 day and 20-30% would have partition of 1 month)

Comment: I'd prefer: 1) Use partitioning. Old partitions should be deleted simply. 2) Create new partitions for future periods and delete old partitions automatically using Event scheduler and according Event procedure. *wont partition deletion cause same issue?* Partition is separate on-disk file, partition deletion causes its file deletion, so fragmentation issue cannot occur. *can we create partitions for an year in advance?* Of course. For a year, for 10 years, for 100 years...

Comment: 1) please ask only one question at a time, no matter how related you think your questions are. 2) First question is does not make much sense as nobody forces you to  use partitioni pruning instead of deletes.